# How to export packages deployed in "Integration Services Catalog" using any command line, C# or T-SQL?

Tags: ssis

I need to export packages deployed in SSISDB by any means to make it automated; so a command line, C# or T-SQL would be fine. I don't want the manual way used by Visual Studio. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it. Use stored procedure in SSISDB "catalog.get_project" which will return project_stream. Save it to a file with ".zip" extension and extract the packages from it.

This is because [as per Microsoft documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/7/5/175A7833-6F75-418D-8800-86D44D1D712D/%5BMS-ISPAC%5D.pdf) the ISPAC file is based on OPC standard which is genuinely was invented by Microsoft and used for pptx, docx ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

IsDeploymentWizard is a good option. You can see parameter usage by typing

```
IsDeploymentWizard -h
```

on the command line.