# Commands Lines / Power Shell Commands to Export the SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, integration, ssis-2012

As far I know, SSIS packages can be deployed using any of the following deployment 
strategies:

1. File system
2. MSDB
3. SSIS Catalog

In file system , we will make use of server agent to trigger the .dtsx file.

For MSDB and Catalog  deployment , we have different steps to follow.

Now the problem ,

I am looking for a way to export the packages and its dependencies from MSDB / SSIS catalog .

These can be doable through GUI (Sql Server Management Studio - Integration Service ).

How to programmatically export the SSIS packages from SSIS Catalog / MSDB using commands / powershell ?

Anyone have idea on this?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707906/how-to-export-packages-deployed-in-integration-services-catalog-using-any-comm

Answer (score 1):

Ashif,
Jamie Thomson's blog for dumping SSIS packages from a server to files should help.

[enter link description here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2011/02/02/export-all-ssis-packages-from-msdb-using-powershell.aspx)