# Extracting dtsx from Integration Service Catalog from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl

From a local C# program, I am trying to connect to an SSMS server's Integration Services Catalog *(SSISDB)* to read the .dtsx file(s) that are in there. I have the IP/u/p of the server, but after that, how would I get the .dtsx files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract SSIS projects *(including dtsx files)* using the [SSISDB.catalog.get_project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-get-project-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15) stored procedure. You should use it to save the project as a ".zip" file and extract the packages from it.

You should call this stored procedure from an SQL Command using C# to extract those files. While searching online I found a solution implemented in PowerShell, you can implement the same logic using c#:

- [Exports all SSIS projects and packages from a SQL Server 2012 and above SSISDB catalog](https://gist.github.com/bseebacher/e088e5a2d3c4325d279c2ed9a8b28197)
- [Get packages from SSIS Catalog](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2016/04/get-packages-from-ssis-catalog.html)
- [Dumping All Your Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Packages to Files with PowerShell](https://brianseebacher.com/posts/ssis-dump-everything/)

---

##### Similar questions:

- [How to export packages deployed in "Integration Services Catalog" using any command line, C# or T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707906/how-to-export-packages-deployed-in-integration-services-catalog-using-any-comm)